# CSS And Mobile View As Desktop Issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and I have my own built table on some page.
This table is showing some info for mobile users and more info for desktop users (because of space).
I'm using css rule

`media only screen and (max-device-width:`

to show the correct info for mobile users (i'm using `display: none` to hide some parts).

Everything works great but, when I click on my mobile browser to view as desktop, it does show as desktop the whole website expect my table which remains the same as mobile (with hidden parts).

What can i do to recognize this situation?

Thanks

Comment: What method are you using to show the desktop version of your page?  You'll likely need some additional attribute (an ID or Class, for instance) that is only present either when the desktop version OR mobile version is rendered in order to override the @media -- if you can update your question with additional info, I'm sure the CSS you need is fairly straightforward

Comment: Hey, 
To show desktop version i'm using my phone browser and click "view as desktop", the problem is that my css show info by width and that the reason it showing the mobile version on the desktop view..

* just note - everything works fine on regluar desktop and mobile version
the only problem is on mobile phone viewing as desktop

Comment: can you share a link to your site? without knowing what the 'view as desktop' link actually does behind the scenes, it's hard to suggest a solution.